# Visual Studio 2019 Dot Net 5 how to store user secret for the entire solution

Tags: .net-core

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2019 that has multiple projects inside, each project represents individual web service. For each project, I have created separate user secret to store database password used in connection string. I would like to have the secret stored in one place if possible, so that I need to change the password only in one place, if it changes. How can I accomplish this ?

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit each .csproj and replace the Guid in UserSecretsId with the same one for each project.

Comment: this may be a silly question , but what do I need to do , if the database password changes ? do I need update all csprojs ?

Comment: The user secrets settings are all stored in a folder with the guid as the key. If you reuse the same guid for multiple .csproj files, then they will all use the same user secrets file. You can then do Manage User Secrets for any of the projects and it'll be shared.